# Jenkins: JUnit Attachments in pipelines

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to migrate some legacy projects in Jenkins into pipelines. I'm currently using https://plugins.jenkins.io/junit-attachments/ to upload snapshots taken by junit on failed tests by configuring "Additional test report features".
However, I don't see how I can invoke this plugin on a pipeline.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do it?